# URLSessionConfiguration's httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost not working in case of network failure

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I am setting the httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost property to 1 on a URLSessionConfiguration object when creating a URLSession.  This allows me to queue a number of downloads ( same host ), but only download 1 file at a time. I use the session for background downloads. All works as expected most of the time but the following fails:

1. Enqueue couple downloads. As expected first starts and the second waits.
2. Go to settings and disable wi-fi. Wait for a second or two and enable it.
3. Get back to the app. What happens is that now both download tasks download data at the same time ignoring httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost setting.

Is this expected and is there any workaround ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/73565

Comment: I already saw that post but it is not quite what i am seeing. For me initially all works. It starts to fail if at least once the download in progress has stopped because let say connection dropped. Once it resumes it switches to range requests and somehow iOs is no longer counting it and starts the next one from the queue together with it.